# Does “little did he know” mean he "knew nothing at all"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

Does the phrase **“little does/did (s)he know”** mean the person knew *nothing at all*?

Or does it literally mean that there was *some* (little) knowledge?

I started pondering the specific meaning when I read the opening titles of *Star Wars Episode VI*:

> *Little does Luke know that the GALACTIC EMPIRE has secretly begun construction …*

In this instance, I believe he did know nothing at all about those sinister schemes.

So, is it just a figure of speech to express that some poor soul should have known?

Comment: It means "he did not know <this specific thing>". So, in your example, Luke was completely unaware that the empire had secretly begun construction (otherwise, it wouldn't be very secret, would it?). But that doesn't mean he doesn't know that "2+2=4" or that Yoda is short and talks weird or that he has a strange crush on a woman who will turn out to be his sister...

Comment: As @DanBron said, it gives the sense of that person being completely unaware of a particular important fact or situation.

Comment: So it does mean he or she did *nothing at all* about the issue at hand‽ (knowing *anything* is understood)

Comment: @dakab Yes, it means *nothing at all* about the matter at hand. As I said: the Death Star wouldn't be much of a secret if he knew about it, would it? It's an idiom, don't try to analyze it literally. People rarely kick buckets when they die, but "to kick the bucket" always means to die, as does "to buy the farm". Idioms are unpredictable.

Comment: What?? His SISTER!?!  Thanks for ruining that one... I suppose Darth Vader will turn out to be his father too...

Comment: And coincidentally...  http://xkcd.com/1769

Comment: It may sound odd to a non-native speaker, that *little* means nothing at all, but it is a very specific idiom used in a slightly dramatic sense, to convey that a vital piece of information was not available to someone. *Little did he know, as he turned the ignition, that someone had placed an explosive device in the boot of his car*.

Comment: 'Little did he/she know...' is often used to highlight how someone who thinks they are in control/well informed, actually, is not.

Comment: Did you look up the word? One of the very first definitions of _little_ as an adverb is “not at all”, with specific examples starting in “Little did he know…”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Sure I did, but the dictionary I use only lists “a bit”, “somewhat”, “scarce”, etc. for *little*, and certainly not “not(hing) at all”.

Comment: With all due respect, and I won't touch your post again, but two different users corrected  `should better have known`, `better should have known` into [**should have known better**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJJT00wqlOo) but each time you reversed the edit. I assure you, as it is currently written, the word order is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: As summarized, those weren't identic edits, with you asserting in rev. 4 that “should have” must not contain an infix, while the point was the position of *better*, which I think is conflicting (thus unintended) depending on position. Isn't the distinction from the rev. 5 comment correct?

Comment: [*better should have known*](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22better+should+have+known%22) gets 7 results on Google Books. If you want to dispute with objective data, go ahead.

Comment: You reordered/repositioned the correct edit twice, but if [**154,000 hits**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22should+have+known+better%22&tbm=bks&start=50) on Google books for **"should have known better"** doesn't convince you, I don't know what else to add.

Comment: @dakab “Better should have known” does not exist in English. It is ungrammatical and does not make any sense. At all. The fixed phrase is “should have known better”; there is no other place to put _better_ than at the end there. The logic in your edit description is not true and doesn't make any sense either.

Answer (score 4):

**[Little](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/little)** when used as an adverb can mean:

> not at all (used before a verb): *He little knows what awaits him.*

This is the same usage as in "little did he know", which hence means "he knew nothing about it".

---

*As per Dan's comment on the question:*

> 'Little did he/she know...' is often used to highlight how someone who thinks they are in control/well informed, actually, is not.

Answer (score 1):

"Little did he know..." means that "he did not know about ..."

For example:

> Little does Luke know that the GALACTIC EMPIRE has secretly begun construction …

This would mean that Luke did not know that "the GALACTIC EMPIRE has secretly begun construction"

It can be re-written as:

> Luke does not know that the GALACTIC EMPIRE has secretly begun construction

(though the first one does sound better)